# Getting unreferenced variable error despite making it global

Tags: python, variables, scope

I'm getting the error

```
  File "C:\Users\danie\Desktop\cf\p16.py", line 25, in count
    n += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment
```

Here is my full code

```
global b
global n
b = []
n = 0

#[some code was cut from here]

def count(row):
    if(row == 7):
        n += 1
        return
    for col in range(8):
        if isValid(row,col):
            A[row][col] = 'q'
        count(row + 1)
        a[row][col] = '.'

b = []
for i in range(8): b.append(list(input()))
n = 0
count(0)
print(n)
```

I've tried making the variable global, defining both before and after the function, right before I call the function. Nothing works, its always referenced before assignment. Sorry for the beginner level question, its just nothing ive read online has helped.

Comment: `global var_name` is used inside a function. Do `global n` then `n += 1` inside your function. See https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value

Comment: _I've tried making the variable global_ Show us what you tried.  We can't point out errors if you don't show the code.

Answer (score 0):

You declared a global `n` before you even assigned it.

It should be:

```
n = 0
b = []
global b
global n
```

Always assign your variables before doing anything else.